# Wrong format of hook get error "An effect function must not return anything besides a function..."

Tags: reactjs, redux, format, react-hooks, next.js

I'm using Next.js to build a page. So this is a react hook component I'm building:

```
const Home = ({ startClock }) => {
  useEffect(() => startClock, []);
  return <>
    <p>{I18n.t("navBarById.361")}</p>
    <Examples />
  </>
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    language: state.i18n || {}
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
   startClock: actions.startClock(dispatch)
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home)
```

So I think somewhere is wrong format of react hook because I got warning

> An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up. You returned: 17
>       in Home (created by ConnectFunction)
>       in ConnectFunction (at pages/index.js:6)

... when I compile code. But I don't know what's my mistake. May you help me solve this mistake, I search on google but I can't find any solution.
Thanks.
This is startClock action:

```
const actions = {
    ....,
    startClock: dispatch => {
        return setInterval(() => {
            dispatch({ type: actions.TICK, light: true, ts: Date.now() })
        }, 1000)
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: what is the use of   `useEffect(() => startClock, []);`  this hook here ??

Comment: @AkhilAravind I have added action startClock for more detail

Comment: FYI, i think the useEffect() call is incorrect, could you please change that to `useEffect(() =>{ startClock() },[]);` and check if the error exists :)

Comment: still have the same issue, or your issue resolved ?

Comment: It's can not run. Got error `TypeError: startClock is not a function` and crash page.

Comment: check the component where you call `home` component, check if it is like `<Home startClock={some_function} />`